# Sharing Multiple Documents in Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document

Is there not a way to share multiple documents from a library at a time, other than a folder?  It seems ridiculously cumbersome to have to individually share 4 separate documents with selected users.  We don't wish to clutter the UI in the document library with multiple folders simply to simplify sharing dox. Why can't we select more than one document and share them in one process.....

Comment: I have the same problem. Waqas answer not work. That give permissions to the entire library. Any other idea? Tks.

Comment: Any update on this?
As far as i know this still is not working.

Comment: Did you ever got an answer? I'm in the same situation. It's awful!

Comment: It is by design and it makes lots of sense to me, as permissions transparensy is considered more important than ease of use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are not able to share multiple document at once.

what i tried and its work for me.

- go to your **Document Library** and select the multiple files( you will see check mark on left side of document)
- Now from the Ribbon Click on **Library**
- from here on 2nd from right select **Shared With** option
- On new pop up, select the **Invite People**
- Click Ok.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Waqas - what you suggested shares the library, not individual files, as you are in the "Library" sharepoint tab.  This is not what we are trying to do.

This does not work for us.  Under the "Files" sharepoint menu tab, as soon as you select more than one document, "Shared With" is greyed out.  This is astonishingly stupid UI behaviour if this is by design.....

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SharePoint is very specific about their Security. In your case, you can create a Folder which will contain documents to be shared and then Share this folder using "Share With".